# Are two matrices similar iff they have the same Jordan Canonical form?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Are two matrices similar if and only if they have the same Jordan Canonical form?

Does the Jordan form have to have ordered eigenvalues?

For example, if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are eigenvalues of $A$, are $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_2&0\\0&\lambda_1\end{pmatrix}$ both Jordan forms of $A$?

Comment: The Jordan normal form exists for complex matrices (or more generally matrices over an algebraically closed field). The eigenvalues of a complex matrix are complex numbers, and there is no natural "order" on $\mathbb C$, so your second question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Up to arbitrary ordering of Jordan blocks, yes
- No
- Yes

Comment: Thanks! That really cleared my problem up!

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues need not be ordered. You can conjugate a diagonal matrix by a permutation matrix to put them in any order.