# Is this a family of similar matrices $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 0&x\\ 0&0 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Is matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ similar to matrix $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&2\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$? If so, how do I prove this?

I came here from following the answer to this question:

[Do similar matrices have equal singular values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744958/do-similar-matrices-have-equal-singular-values)

Comment: Could you please explain why I got downvoted? This will help me avoid the same mistake in the future? Is this question too simple?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017581/are-two-matrices-similar-iff-they-have-the-same-jordan-canonical-form

Comment: I would guess that you have been downvoted for not showing any effort. The form of your matrices $A,B$ makes computing the product $S A S^{-1}$ for $S = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ where $S$ is to be determined very easy, and you might not have needed to ask the question. Or if you are still stuck, then adding this to your question would help someone write an answer that actually helps you, instead of giving you a textbook answer

Comment: It should be simple to find a basis change that shows your matrices to be similar. It can even be diagonal!

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks for the hint. I got it now. I will post an answer to my own question, when I am back from work this afternoon.

Comment: Do you know how to find the Jordan normal form of a matrix?  This answers the question "are these matrices similar" in a mechanical way.  Since $A$ already is in Jordan form, you only have to do $B$.

Comment: If $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,d_2)$ is any diagonal matrix, what is $DAD^{-1]$. Can you choose $d_1$ and $d_2$ in such way that $DAD^{-1}=B$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are similar then

$\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix} 0&2\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix} $

for some invertible matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix}$.

Try to calculate such matrix $P$ from the above condition.